# why did my CPVC joint fail?

Tags: plumbing

Over the weekend, a neighbor tried to remove a water softener installed outside their house, and broke the lines. I helped them fix it, but one of the solvent welded joints I made failed. The main water line is PVC and the piping in the house is CPVC. We used a slip transition coupler to go from PVC to CPVC. We used Purple Primer and All Purpose Cement, both labeled for use with PVC and CPVC.

I normally wait 30 minutes after cementing these types of joints before applying water pressure, but the water was turned on only a few minutes later. The joint between the coupler and the CPVC separated.

I primed and cemented both surfaces again, and reassembled the joint. 45 minutes later, I turned on the water and the joint failed again.

My neighbor was able to locate a sharkbite transition adapter at a hardware store 30 minutes away, so we ended up fixing it with that.

So my questions are:

1. Why did the coupler and CPVC pipe separate the first time? I thought that this type of cement sets within minutes.
2. Why did the joint fail a second time?

Comment: Did you hold the two ends of the pipe together (e.g a clamping action) for any length of time? Also, most pipe glues I have seen should set within 15 minutes but take a few hours to fully cure.

Comment: For the second time, was joint cleaned back to virgin plastic?  Quite a few glues will not bond well to themselves.

Comment: Yes, something was very wrong if the joint actually came apart. PVC cement welds the parts almost instantly. There's no going back after 30 seconds.

Comment: @crip659 For the second attempt, I probably did not clean the coupling enough. I cut the end off the pipe, though, so that was fresh.

Comment: What did the instructions say and what was the temperature? When the temps are low solvent welding agents do not cure as quickly. I will  pressurize fairly quickly in the summer but winter give plenty of time, also larger pipes take longer.

Comment: Let's be clear... this isn't "glue". It's a solvent-based cement that actually dissolves the plastic briefly, welding them together. It's _really_ hard to screw that up if the parts are coated well. This sounds like a problem with the cement.

Comment: I'll have to test the cement then. I'm in Florida, so the temperatures are warm.

Comment: Please post a picture of the primer and cement which you used. I'm sure you used the right stuff but it never hurts to have a second set of eyes verify.

Comment: Did you apply 1/4 turn as you inserted the pipe? The instructions say that it should be a 2 hour cure time. If you didn't use a clean pipe the second time then I am not surprised it failed the second time.

Comment: Did you check the outside of the pipe and make sure there is no paint or other surface protection coating? The cement will 100% fail if there's another layer. Typically I go over the surface with turpentine just in case someone painted it over with a waterproofing layer, or even try scratching the surface with a knife and see if there's a layer I couldn't detect.